# Laravel sentinel login not working

Tags: laravel, sentinel

I used `Laravel 5` version with `Sentinel` package for `authentication`. I followed  [this instruction](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#laravel-5)

`Registration` works fine. but `login` not return anything.

```
        $credentials = [
            "email"    => 'test@gmail.com',
            "password" => 'password'
        ];


        $user = Sentinel::authenticate($credentials);
        print_r($user);
        exit;
```

`$user` returns `empty` even I given correct email & password.

(eg: Data)
`Users` table has the following data

```
Email            Password
test@gmail.com   $2y$10$Wu2dY8zQNJPBR
```

Anyone direct me, how do I debug this issue to fix it? or any useful ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does this return when you use it Sentinel::findByCredentials($credentials);

Comment: @MwaaJoseph, Sentinel::findByCredentials($credentials);  also give empty response

Answer (score 1):

I finally fix this issue. Sometime we can not find the small problem :)

The problem is password length which was changed by me 20 characters. But `sentinel` encrypting the password before storing to db table. this encrypted length is more than 20 characters.

Partial password only stored in the DB. that's why Login was not working.

I changed the following line in migration

```
$table->string('password', 20);
```

to

```
$table->string('password');
```

So now the password length should be 255 character which is VARCHAR default length.